# generate random number for every 5 seconds in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

```
random = Random.new.rand(1..50)
puts random
```

This code keep generating a random number for every milli seconds. i want to generate a random     number for every 5 seconds . 
something like this,

```
random = (Random.new.rand(1..50), 5000)
```

where 5000 refers to time (generate random number between 1 to 50 for every 5 seconds)

Comment: I am not so familiar with Ruby, but i suggest you can create and run a thread that generates a random number every __ seconds (maybe make it sleep that long at the end of every loop) based on the parameter passed.

Comment: thanks for your comment. got the answer using sleep() method @HitenNareshVasnani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sleep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) to suspend the current thread:

```
while true
  puts rand(50) + 1
  sleep 5
end
```